# Randomly pick mixin

Tags: sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I have three mixins each consisting of a different background image SVG that has a colour passed to them (simplified examples):

```
@mixin svg-1($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="foobar"></svg>');
}
@mixin svg-2($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="barfoo"></svg>');
}
@mixin svg-3($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="blabla"></svg>');
}
```

I am then trying to randomly pick any three of these on compilation by doing something like this:

```
@include svg-#{random(3)}($color);
```

This is giving me a compilation error of:

```
Error: property "#{random(3)}" must be followed by a ':'
```

Am I using the wrong syntax here or is this just not the right method for handling this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you change only the paths, another solution is to put these paths in a list, take one at random (using `nth()` function => see the documentation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) and put it as background-image.

Something like this:

```
$paths: 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'blabla';

@mixin svg($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="#{nth($paths, random(length($paths)))}"></svg>');
}

div{
  @include svg(purple);
}
```

If you do so, you can add as many paths as you want in your list without worrying about putting another @if in your mixin. :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing my three mixins to one that takes a number:

```
@mixin svg($num, $color) {
    @if ($num == 1) {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="foobar"></svg>');
    }

    @if ($num == 2) {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="barfoo"></svg>');
    }

    @if ($num == 3) {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="blabla"></svg>');
    }
}
```

and is then called by passing a random number like this:

```
@include svg(random(3), $color);
```

Comment: If you change only a path you can do a path list using `nth($path, random(length($path)))` in a mixin without any @if.

Comment: @ReSedano your suggestion would give I think a better solution than the accepted answer. You may want to consider posting it as a solution so readers can view a alternative solution which I feel is better.

Comment: You are right, @B68C. I add also my idea. Thanks for your consideration. :)

Answer (score 0):

try used a only function that returns the property that you will like apply. i used this code:

```
@mixin svgRandom($color) {
    $randomNum : random(3);
    @if $randomNum == 1 {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="foobar"></svg>');
    } @else if $randomNum == 2 {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="barfoo"></svg>');
    } @else if $randomNum == 3 {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><g fill="#{$color}"><path d="blabla"></svg>');
    }
}
```

And call it that:

```
@include svgRandom(#00ff00);
```

Comment: Thanks Kike, I prefer this solution to the one that I came up with as it is DRY-er